# How to access element in XML files with attribute values?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

This is my XML file

```
<colleges>

    <college college_name="DYPSOE">
        <departments>
            <department department_name="Computer" id="10">
            <![CDATA[I NEED TO CHANGE THIS COMMENT!]]>
            </department>
            <department department_name="Machanical" id="20">
            <![CDATA[I NEED TO CHANGE THIS COMMENT!]]>
            </department>
        </departments>
    </college>

    <college college_name="DYPSOET">
        <departments>
            <department department_name="Computer" id="10">
            <![CDATA[I NEED TO CHANGE THIS COMMENT!]]>
            </department>
            <department department_name="Machanical" id="20">
            <![CDATA[I NEED TO CHANGE THIS COMMENT!]]>
            </department>
        </departments>
    </college>

</colleges>
```

I have three attribute values as college_name, department_name and id available in the program. So I want to go to the particular "Department" node and change the value in the comments with these three attribute values.

I'am trying to reach the node with different queries, failed so far.

```
var node = from e in doc.Descendants("college")
           where e.Attribute("college_name").ToString() == college_name
           select (XElement)e.Elements("department");


foreach (XElement data in node)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data); //Just to look what I got
    data.Value = ""; //To change the comment section
}
```

This is not working at all. If you guys could suggest me the query it would help me a lot.

Comment: There are typos for a start (college / collage)

Comment: Sorry, let me edit this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you want to select a single department element based on college and department names, you can find it using a query like this one:

```
var query = from college in doc.Descendants("college")
            where (string) college.Attribute("college_name") == "DYPSOE"
            from department in college.Descendants("department")
            where (string) department.Attribute("department_name") == "Computer"
            select department;

var element = query.Single();
```

You can then replace the comment like this:

```
element.ReplaceNodes(new XCData("new comment"));
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot :) Charles Mager

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`System.Xml.XmlReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to read the nodes' attribute and write it with [`System.Xml.XmlWriter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/system.xml.xmlwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
[How to: Parse XML with XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/library/cc189056%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) has the example of parsing and writing.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend this except in special cases (e.g. huge files).  This is a very low level API, and something like LINQ to XML makes this much more straight forward (it uses these things under the covers).

Comment: I think maybe @the_dragonknight is just trying to make his question simple... But yes, if the file isn't huge, using other methods may be faster and easier. :)

Comment: @J3soon yes, I have a huge file and have to use a lot of recursion to get to the particular nodes. I needed idea to fetch the nodes and edit them like this. And yes, was trying to make the question simpler :)